# Global interception of a particular keyboard in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have a small handheld device that is made for game control on mobile devices.  It pairs via Bluetooth and appears as just another keyboard.  This device will pair with desktop OS's as well, it just appears as another bluetooth HID keyboard.

I intend to make a .NET application to address an accessibility issue (limited mobility) using this device.

I've seen the various threads on StackOverflow detailing how to create global keyboard hooks (LowLevelKeyboardProc) when the app is running but none appear to address the case of multiple keyboards.

Is it possible to globally hook all keystrokes from a particular Bluetooth keyboard?  If not, is it possible to intercept all HID key codes coming from a HID device and preventing them from being sent to Windows?